# Backup-SqlDatabase PsDrive Filesystem

Tags: powershell, backup-sqldatabase

I'm trying to backup a SQL database to a remote location, with the `Backup-SqlDatabase` cmdlet, to a PSDrive (filesystem) with no success.

I am creating a PSDrive for example \\server\sharedFolder with a name TARGET.

```
New-PSDrive –Name TARGET -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server\sharedfolder -Credential (Get-Credentials)
```

but when I run the backup like:

```
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $server -Database $dbName -BackupFile "TARGET:bckfile.bak" -Credential $sqlCredentials
```

I get a completely different location and error:

> Backup-SqlDatabase : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Cannot open backup device 'E:\SQL_BCK\TARGET\TARGET:bckfile.bak'. Operating system error 
>   3 (The system cannot find the path specified.).

But if I run the backup like:

```
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $server -Database $dbName -BackupFile "\\server\sharedfolder\bckfile.bak" -Credential $sqlCredentials
```

I have no problems.

The issue is, I need to access the shared folder with different credentials, so the PSDrive was the perfect solution, because during configration I ask the user for credentials.

Comment: How do you create the psdrive `TARGET`? If you create it on your local workstation, it isn't visible on the server that is actually writing the data.

Comment: New-PSDrive –Name TARGET -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server\sharedfolder -Credential (Get-Credentials)... the target is correct... but doesn't work when used in the backup-sqldatabase

Comment: Try `New-PSDrive ... -Persist`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `-Scope "Script"` into `New-PSDrive`

Check Scope section in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-6)